# Why does this question have 4 votes to migrate to Meta?

Tags: bug, vote-to-close

Why is [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/417707/thunderbird-not-sending-emails-from-ubuntu-host) being shown [on a review](https://askubuntu.com/review/close/219927)?

> [image]

It has 4 close votes to *migrate to Meta*.

Why does it have 4 migration votes (unrelated to Meta)?

That option isn't even available for me on most questions (though I remember seeing it sometimes).

Comment: This just cropped up again [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/420772/176889). I fail to believe that a close voter intentionally selected OT > Migrate > Meta. Thus, I believe this should be reopened and it should be explained why/how this happens (bug?).

Comment: [Because nobody read reviews](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8421/reviewers-need-to-be-mindful-of-their-actions?cb=1)

Comment: @Braiam: I thought so at first, but if the 3 that followed were just copying the first, then why would the first person vote to migrate to Meta?