# Reviewers *need* to be mindful of their actions!

Tags: discussion

A new answer popped up on an old question earlier and it popped into the Late Answer review queue. Imagine you're reviewing... Does this look like a good answer?

> 0 Ubuntu Software Center “Failed to download…” 0 Ubuntu Software Center doesn't let me install any software Hot Network Questions Block employee access to public cloud How do KLT and SVD differ from each other? What application supports working with sprites (PNGs) over 10,000 px wide? Can someone explain the ECB Penguin?

It's a bunch of nonsense copied from the sidebar.
It's not an answer.
It's easy to see that *if you read it*.

And that's the problem. Some reviewers aren't reading what they're being asked to. That's the entire point of review: read it, read the question (if applicable) and work out whether something needs to be done to fix, improve or remove the post.

This isn't the first time this has happened but I want people to know that I want it to be the last. It's not fair on the other reviewers to allow this to happen.

### Rushing review hurts the site and wastes others' time.

If you don't have time, don't review, somebody else will do it properly. If you can't understand or don't know which way to vote, click the skip button. Do not bulk-action a load of stuff without reading it.

We've been through this before and I've talked to offenders directly but from now on **if I catch you *willfully bombing* a review queue, you will end up with a review ban**.

And yes, if you see somebody else doing this (the review history is public to many users), this is something we need to be told about. Don't harass the user, just flag one of the incorrectly reviewed posts and use the Other reason to point out the problem and we can be thorough with our investigation.

Comment: I think [this should](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7812/should-we-get-review-audits) at least make them more cautious about their actions.

Comment: Thank you for bringing this up... Lately, I have been coming across users who seemed to be clicking buttons as soon as the page loaded in their browsers - haven't flagged anyone except a few in the past. Should flag more such users who seem to be abusing the system as I come across them..

Comment: I only see my own review history - are those "many" to whom the history is public the >10k users?

Comment: @guntbert Yes only >10k rep users can see the other users' review history.

Comment: @guntbert: Review history is public for anyone to see - [for instance mine](http://askubuntu.com/users/114818/aditya?tab=activity&sort=reviews)... Go to a users profile >> Activity >> Reviews

Comment: @aditya but for using this you must already have some suspicion?

Comment: @guntbert: See the [image in this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170639/205516).... I have come across a couple of such instances and flagged some of them....

Comment: Who reviews the reviewers?

Comment: I agree with at @Oli (how not to?) but as a new-promoted reviewer, I am a bit unpleased by how the system work. Example: I start a review, read it, ponder, and decide to reject. And a message pops up: this review has been already approved. (If you try to modify the text is even more probable). This is at least wasted time (mine). The system should *wait* for the needed reviewers to finish before letting another one even starting doing the review... (with a timeout, but a reasonable one).

Comment: @Rmano We need to point it on MSO if that is the case.

Comment: @Mahesh it happened to me at least two times. What is MSO?

Comment: [meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com). It is the meta site for all network wide discussions. It should probably be called meta Stack Exchange, but meh.

Comment: I like the idea of checking-out review items. [I've requested it on MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221985/can-reviewers-have-reserved-time-when-theyre-reviewing-a-post). Still, it's quite a big request so don't expect it to happen overnight (if at all).

Comment: @Oli I don't think this should be featured any longer than it has been. The message has gotten through now, I think. Especially given the "if I catch you..." and the highlighted `*need*` which makes this post a tiny bit negative and needlessly intimidating. I cannot take away the `feature` tag, however. That is up to you.

Comment: Update: I flagged this question. Because I think it has been featured for too long. Answer: "declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it". Too bad. This is [not the first time](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/181170/213643) that the tone is needlessly hard. I will edit the question. Or at least try to.

Comment: @don.joey You underestimate the damage bad/robo reviewers do. If you review fine how is it intimidating?

Comment: @Aditya I would flag them (users who robo review). Robo reviewers are *really, really* bad. Sometimes they just need a talking to, but no one will talk to them if they don't know it is needed ;)

Comment: @don.joey So just because you don't think robo reviewers will read it means you shouldn't post it? Besides, reminders are always good. IMO you are being much too sensitive.

Comment: @Seth Bad robot...

Comment: @don.joey I guess you have a different understanding of robo-reviewers... Robo-reviewers are someone who go through the reviews extremely fast without paying any attention to what they are reviewing.. They sort-of click the review buttons as soon as the page loads in their browsers. People who actually pay some attention while reviewing items shouldn't be worried at all. If someone is bad at reviewing - it's fine - [they need to be tutored on how to perform those review tasks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214541/205516) - they are not supposed to be banned :-)

Comment: @don.joey For any other problem I'd agree but reviewers (even the less attentive) are more integrated into the site than other users. I already know who spends least time on each review and they're the sort of people who are also active here on Meta. You'd recognise their names. People can get lazy (or arrogant) once they've been doing review for a while. This post is here to remind *all reviewers* that it's an important job that underpins site quality.

Comment: @Oli Point taken. I guess I don't have the same info you have. Thanks for replying.

Comment: Well, I've got banned because I tried to IMPROVE the test (deliberately wrong) answer. Why is that a problem? In some cases it is better to improve instead of rejecting, isn't?

Comment: @Rmano This is a fundamental 'maybe problem' in SO. There is no reservation or locking on resources (question, reviews, etc). I'm not sure if it is solvable, though.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps adding a back button for review cues would reduce the possibility of reviewer error going uncorrected.

Comment: Bad suggestion? why?