# Call out to reviewers - you CAN "skip"

Tags: discussion, review

I remember some reviews of suggested edits where the reviewers clearly could not understand either the post or the edit.

One of these was https://askubuntu.com/a/476746/117103 , supposedly an answer, which it isn't. I don't blame anybody for not understanding Italian - but it isn't at all useful to "improve" a non-answer of the species "I have the problem too".

So please: If you don't understand a post or the suggested edit, be it

- because of a language barrier
- because you are not familiar with the topic
- because the subtleties escape you
- ...

don't hesitate to press the [image: skip] button!

---

As has been suggested I want to add that the same applies to **all** review queues - although the reason *language barrier* will not be so frequent there :-)

Comment: Screenshot for non 10k users (the post is now deleted): http://i.imgur.com/coQBuGm.png. [here](http://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/272338) is the review.

Comment: Related: [Reviewers *need* to be mindful of their actions!](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8421/reviewers-need-to-be-mindful-of-their-actions)

Comment: Cross site  related [There is no shame in using “Skip”](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195/792066)

Comment: However, edit made clearer that it's not an answer (I don't need to know the Italian to determine "Depends:" markdown) and reviewers ideally should go to the post and flag it.

Comment: Just need a clarification... Even if i am not in the suggested edits queue i can press skip if i am facing a difficulty??

Comment: @venki that applies to all review queues.

Comment: @guntbert Probably add this in your description?

Comment: The most useful button I have encountered.