# Reminder to everyone: You can use the "skip" button if you don't know what the question/answer is about!

Tags: discussion

## [Call out to reviewers - you CAN "skip"](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/9241/call-out-to-reviewers-you-can-skip)

<sub>Yeah, I know: I'll be voting to close my own question as a duplicate now...</sub>